# Can't read data from Firestore Database

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have two applications, a mobile app that writes data on a Firestore Database and a desktop app that basically reads them. The problem is that when data are written from the mobile app on the database, the desktop app doesn't read them. Documents appear to be non-existent although they actually exists in the correct collection and with the correct id.

If I manually create the same document, the desktop app reads it. Code to find the document is the following:

```
      final int currentYear = DateTime.now().year; // current year documents
  final String documentId =
      "$selectedPatient, $currentYear"; // document id
  DocumentReference patientDocument =
      gameCollection.document(documentId); // point at the doc

  if (!await patientDocument.exists) {
    return "noExists"; // check if doc exists
  }
```

Basically, when documents are dynamically generated from the mobile app the desktop app doesn't see them and returns "noExists". When manually generated, everything works fine. I thought it could be a problem related to data synchronization between different apps but, even after 12 or more hours the problem persists. Is there something I can do to solve the problem?

Comment: Show us the exact document that you want to read using that code.